# How do I fetch List of all the available Bluetooth Devices after a scan and do it at certain intervals?

Tags: android, list, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

well I tried

```
reciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {     
@Override    
public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Devices Found" ,` `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`


BluetoothDevice devicex;
 devicex =intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if(!devicer.contains(devicex))
                {devicer.add(devicex);list.add(devicex.getName());}
            }}};
```

But this only fetches one device. I need to collect all the available devices in a list and display it in a listview. Also I want to repeat scanning at certain interval of time (using TimerTask). How should I do that.

Comment: your code is incomplete for what you are asking. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Leave fetching over a time interval. I need to know how to get multiple available bluetooth devices instead of just one after a scan.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have available devices around your smartphone?
Could you add logs for actions? For example, `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED`,`BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED`,`BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND`.

Answer (score 0):

Well `BluetoothDevice device1 =` `intent.getParceableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);` is good to fetch only one available device. And 
`ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> list=intent.getParceableArrayListExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);` throwing `"Attempt to invoke Null Object Reference errors"` 
So I found a working Solution.

just put multiple lines like this.

```
BluetoothDevice devicex;
                devicex = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if(!list.contains(devicex))
                {list.add(devicex);}
                devicex = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if(!list.contains(devicex))
                {list.add(devicex);}
                devicex = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if(!list.contains(devicex))
                {list.add(devicex);}
```

these statement will fetch an available device and add it to list if it is not already present in it and then do it again for another available devices. There are no other ways in the developers guide to do this.
These statements runs in linear time. So they might not cause any problem.

Suggest correction if needed.